# Create a seamless image crop over original image with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to crop an image using a `canvas`, and position that crop over the original image in a seamless way, so that the separation wouldn't be visible.

Here's what I would have expected to work:

```
const image = document.querySelector("img")
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvasCoords = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
ctx.drawImage(
  image,
  canvasCoords.left, canvasCoords.top,
  canvasCoords.width, canvas.height,
  0, 0,
  canvasCoords.width, canvasCoords.height
)
```

I want the crop to fill my canvas, hence the last 4 properties. `canvasCoords`. Also I am aware that a real-life solution would involve getting the canvas offset relatively to the image, but this is just a simplified example.

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv6543ef/5/) of that example.

Comment: drawImage uses the natural size of your image but your element is resized through css. So you indeed need to set the sizes of your drawn image relative to the size of the element, or to not set the <img> size through css at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the width and height scales using `image.naturalWidth / image.width` and `image.naturalHeight / image.height` like below:

```js
const image = document.querySelector("img")
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvasCoords = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
const widthScale = image.naturalWidth / image.width
const heightScale = image.naturalHeight / image.height
ctx.drawImage(
  image,
  canvasCoords.left * widthScale, canvasCoords.top * heightScale,
  canvasCoords.width * widthScale, canvas.height * heightScale,
  0, 0,
  canvasCoords.width, canvasCoords.height
)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 175px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.savoie-mont-blanc.com/var/smb/storage/images/media/images/visites-et-decouvertes/nature/lac-des-vaches-a-pralognan-la-vanoise-parc-national-de-la-vanoise/359903-1-fre-FR/Lac-des-Vaches-a-Pralognan-la-Vanoise-Parc-national-de-la-Vanoise_default_format.jpg">
  <canvas width="150" height="50"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can hide the image from the page and do everything in the canvas, you can use the trick of drawing the canvas again:

```
ctx.drawImage(
  canvas,
  0, 0,
  150,50,
  0,0,150,50
)
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv6543ef/27/)